# What is happening when I press Control-C in the R terminal?

Tags: r, terminal

I open a Windows command prompt. I run R `R`. When I press Control-C in the R terminal, something weird happens. It appears to exit R and take me back to the command prompt, BUT now when I type commands they are fought over by the command prompt and a R terminal hiding in the background . What's going on?

```
C:\Users\hickfordm>R

R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)

> ^C
c:\users\hickfordm>dir
'ir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

c:\users\hickfordm>
Error: object 'd' not found
```

Edit: This happens to me only if I run `R`. If I run `Rterm`, control-C does nothing, which is reasonable.

Comment: Aye. Owen, if you run Windows can you try this and see what happens?

Comment: Results from my Win-7 machine below, interrupting a loop, no results such as this.  If nothing is running, ^C is ignored.  What was running in your session at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend was able to reproduce this on Windows with `R`, but not `Rterm`. Doesn't happen on Linux. This must be a bug in R. I'll endeavour to report it https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14948

---

Fixed upstream, expect fix to make R 2.16

---

Meanwhile, fixed in R *patched* 2.15.1 http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html (not vanilla 2.15.1)

Answer (score 0):

In R terminal, try this:

```
>while(1){}
```

and then type control + c.

I try it on Linux. When I type control + c, the loop terminal. But R terminal didn't exit. I didn't try it on Windows.

Comment: Not really a useful answer as the OP does not use linux. Under linux crtl+c raises a keyboard interrupt, killing the then running operation.

Comment: Oi! This is a useful answer, thanks. Other users use Linux (including myself sometimes)

Comment: I just tried this with Windows 7 64-bit, R 2.14.2.  Same results as xiao, the loop exited with a ^C, but RTerm did not.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Good question. I tried it `while(1){print("1")}`. When I pressed control-c, it took me back to the command prompt. About 10 lines of 1's carried on printing then they stopped.

Comment: This only happens with `R` and not `Rterm`, sorry my original question was unclear.